# How to get input type Button in Listview Itemdatabound event using ASP.net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, listview

I am working on an asp.net application event where I am binding event. there is some value in session which i have assigned in datatable. Now I want that if the ProductID in the binded listview and session ProductID matches the button should gets disabled. Here is my code to Bind Listview.

```
dt = new ProductImages().SelectProductsWithImages();

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    ListFeatured.DataSource = dt;
    ListFeatured.DataBind();
}
```

In the listview there is button of html type as:

```
<input type="button" class="button_type_4 bg_scheme_color r_corners tr_all_hover color_light mw_0 m_bottom_15" 
       value="Add to Cart" id="btnCart" onclick="Cart(this);" />
```

I want to access this button. For accessing this button I have used following

```
protected void ListFeatured_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            Label lblpid = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblPid");
            long pid = Convert.ToInt64(lblpid.Text);
            Control btnCart = (Control)e.Item.FindControl("btnCart");

            var b = e.Item.FindControl("btnCart");
            DataRow[] row = dtDetails.Select("ProductID=" + pid);

            if (row.Length > 0)
            {
                //b.Visible=
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
}
```

But the value of button of input type always comes null. Please help me someone here.

Comment: For accessing this button on Server side you have to use `runat="server"` in the button markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make this html button as server control by adding `runat="server"`

```
<input type="button" runat="server" class="button_type_4 bg_scheme_color r_corners tr_all_hover color_light mw_0 m_bottom_15" value="Add to Cart" id="btnCart"  onclick="Cart(this);" />
```

After this in code behind you can find this control by casting it to `HtmlInputButton` class

```
HtmlInputButton btnCart = (HtmlInputButton)e.Item.FindControl("btnCart");
```

Comment: Yes it worked right. Is there any way to access this button using jquery?

Comment: Yes, you can access this using jquery but you need to provide me some info how you want to access it.

Comment: actually For each Product-Details  there is a button.There may be multiple Product and against that there is a button in that column or row. When i click on the button the product related to that button should gets submitted to the database and that appropriate button should gets disabled so that user can not click on that. How i can do that.

Comment: If looking through Jquery you need create a webmethod for that else if want to perform server operation use Repeater `ItemCommand`